# Event when user without access trying to update

Tags: sharing

Is it possible to have event(trigger) when user without access to specific account trying to edit the record and get the insufficient privileges message?

It seems not, as such action doesn't run triggers. Seems that SF checking the privileges before running any other logic, but I'm wondering if someone had similar requirement and how it can be handle?

Only W/A I can think is to expand the sharing setup (perhaps set the object as public read/write), and then check the access in trigger.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to detect case when user trying to edit record that he is not supposed to edit... The sharing setup will block him, but I want to sent email alert in this event

Comment: You might be able to use [Transaction Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/module/transaction_security) with a policy on resource access. Although I think that is limited to connected apps.